# Multiple HTTP Requests in WinRT / Win8

Tags: windows-8, windows-runtime

Is it possible to send more than two HTTP requests concurrently in WinRT? I'm trying to load multiple JSON documents from a server and HttpWebRequest fails to respond after the second call. Here is a sample snippet that illustrates this:

```
protected async override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    const string url = "http://www.bom.gov.au/fwo/IDV60901/IDV60901.94868.json";
    const int iterations = 3;

    var tasks = new List<Task>();
    var ticks = DateTime.Now.Ticks;

    for (var i = 0; i < iterations; i++)
    {
        // Create unique URL by appending a generated number.
        var uniqueUrl = string.Format("{0}?v={1}", url, (i + ticks));

        // Create the request.
        var request = WebRequest.CreateHttp(uniqueUrl);

        // Create the async task and store it for later.
        var task = request.GetResponseAsync();

        tasks.Add(task);
    }

    // Await all tasks in collection.
    await Task.WhenAll(tasks);



    Debugger.Break(); // <----- This will never break when iterations > 2
}
```

Put this code in a blank ***MainPage.xaml.cs*** and play around with the iterations value. If you set it to 2, then it works. Anything above that, it will fail.

**NOTE** :: Do not use Fiddler when testing this. Fiddler does something funny and it allows all these connections to go through. I don't know how nor why. You can test this yourself. If you run the code above with fiddler open, then success.

**NOTE** :: This is not real code. I'm only using this example to illustrate the issue.

Comment: Can you show your code, please?  It's hard to diagnose otherwise. :)

Comment: Is this not because the HTTP spec says that only a maximum of two requests can be in flight against a given host at any given time from the client?

Comment: @DominicHopton: isn't that a browser issue? Why would WinRT block me from connecting more than twice? Also, all platforms allow you to make multiple requests, but they internally manage the queue. Only 2 go at a time, but WinRT just throws your requests away.

Comment: @ZombieSheep - My code has lots of other bits to it. It would be a mess to copy/paste it here. I'll try to create a small version of it :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't tried using the `WebClient` API in WinRT, I've only used the `HttpClient` API (which I'm using quite extensively in my application).

This code works:

```
const string url = "http://www.bom.gov.au/fwo/IDV60901/IDV60901.94868.json";
const int iterations = 10;

var tasks = new List<Task<HttpResponseMessage>>();
var ticks = DateTime.Now.Ticks;

for (var i = 0; i < iterations; i++)
{
    // Create unique URL by appending a generated number.
    var uniqueUrl = string.Format("{0}?v={1}", url, (i + ticks));

    var handler = new HttpClientHandler();

    var client = new HttpClient(handler)
                        {
                            BaseAddress = new Uri(uniqueUrl)
                        };

    var task = client.GetAsync(client.BaseAddress);

    tasks.Add(task);
}

// Await all tasks in collection.
await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
```

It is a bit more tedious to get out the response body though as you need to do an async read of all the responses like so:

```
var responseTasks = tasks.Select(task => task.Result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync());

await Task.WhenAll(responseTasks);
```

Then you can iterate through the `responseTask` objects and take their result.

Comment: Thanks @Slace. I was hoping for a solution where I can continue using WebRequest. I have some reusable code sitting in Portable Libraries where HttpClient is not available. I'll have to take it apart a bit to make it work.

Comment: I noticed that using the HttpClient, it throws away custom headers sent down with the response. Please look at this post if you can help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12578022/httpclient-missing-response-headers-in-winrt-win8