# HttpClient missing response headers in WinRT / Win8

Tags: .net, windows-8, windows-runtime, dotnet-httpclient

I'm using HttpClient in a Windows 8 app and it seems that it purposely hides custom headers in the response. For example:

Our response received has a custom header called **"Sample-Header: 123"**

I expect that the headers in the response content would contain "Sample-Header" with a value of "123"

```
var client = new HttpClient();
var response = await client.GetAsync(uri);

string sample;
IEnumerable<string> values;

if (response.Content.Headers.TryGetValues("Sample-Header", out values))
{
   // This never happens!
   sample = values.First();
}
```

Even if I enumerate through the headers, I'll never find our custom headers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok. Apparently, there are two different header collections you could use. The following code works:

```
var client = new HttpClient();
var response = await client.GetAsync(uri);

string sample;
IEnumerable<string> values;

if (response.Headers.TryGetValues("Sample-Header", out values))
{
   // This happens!
   sample = values.First();
}
```

Do you see the difference? Content headers are completely different from response headers.

Thanks to Govind from Microsoft.