# HTTP concurrent limit in WinRT

Tags: http, windows-8, winrt-xaml

I want to watch IpCamera in the metro app, below image is the effect image, each camera request is http persistent connection, so there five concurrent requests at one time, but only two cameras responsed, the others not responsed.

Someone say [two concurrent requests is the default setting for winrt](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/windowsapps/en-US/4b9bfefc-fb94-47fe-b3a3-1a5e4c97f2c2/concurrent-http-requests-bug-in-windows-8-and-defaultconnectionlimit),.

Is there anyone know the reason? Or how to change the default setting for winrt?

[image]

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12525887/multiple-http-requests-in-winrt-win8